# Property does not exist on type: Why does TypeScript complain while JavaScript doesn't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, properties

In the following code

```
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";

function ProfileContent() {
    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();

    const name = accounts[0] && accounts[0].name;
```

`JavaScript` has no problem with this, and the code works as expected. But when I make this a `TypeScript` file, I get errors that

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Partial<Pick<AccountInfo, "homeAccountId" | "localAccountId" | "username">>

What has so drastically changed to the point that TypeScript believes the property within the library doesn't even exist?

Comment: You might be accessing the `accounts` object outside of the msal-react context. Here is some documentation for that particular NPM library: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/4a10d7c57ee5d03be9298b9f1f6bbb86cce54ce1/lib/msal-react/docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing through the source code, it looks like they might have used the wrong type in `IMsalContext`. There's a commit on the `dev` branch with the message ["Fix accounts type"](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/commit/498654d36fed9426328528db387cff7603bf29dd#diff-b549e9c487306819e52f7d34424028db7f2b5c92c776c4f19cb589708083a9ae).

Here is the current [released version](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/msal-v1.4.11/lib/msal-react/src/MsalContext.ts), the [dev branch version](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/src/MsalContext.ts), the [pull request](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/3677), and the [associated issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/3665).

Comment: Confirmed with the dev team that this was/is a bug. Thanks!